# Read line by line column exculding header from Processed_files.csv and search each line in Responsed_File_Name.csv

Tags: shell

I want to read below two csv file line by line (first column) and write it to another report.csv. Take the string from first column without extension (.json) and search the string to another file without extension (_SUCCESS.csv,_ERROR.csv,INPROCESS.csv) and if found update t`enter code here`he report.csv with input file name and output file name with status (SUCCESS,ERROR,INPROCESS,Not_Found)

```
    **Input files**

    **Processed_files.csv**

    **Input File Name,Start Date**
    Out_ch_pc_88882.77.json,2018/10/26  16.38.54  
    Out_pc_fh_42652.48.json,2018/10/26  16.38.54  
    Out_pc_kl_55684.37.json,2018/10/26  17.38.54  
    Out_pc_gl_34454.66.json,2018/10/27  12.38.54  


    **Responsed_File_Name.csv**


    **Output File Name,End Time/Date**

    Out_ch_pc_88882.77_SUCCESS.csv,2018/10/30  14.53.26
    Out_pc_fh_42652.48_ERROR.csv,2018/10/26  17.40.44
    Out_pc_kl_55684.37_INPROCESS.csv,2018/10/26  18.55.14

    **Output files**

    **Input File Name,Start Date,Output File Name,End Time/Date,Status**

    Out_ch_pc_88882.77.json,2018/10/26  16.38.54,Out_ch_pc_88882.77_SUCCESS.csv,2018/10/30  14.53.26,SUCCESS
    Out_pc_fh_42652.48.json,2018/10/26  16.38.54,Out_pc_fh_42652.48_ERROR.csv,2018/10/26  17.40.44.ERROR
    Out_pc_kl_55684.37.json,2018/10/26  17.38.54,Out_pc_kl_55684.37_INPROCESS.csv,2018/10/26  18.55.14,INPROCESS
    Out_pc_gl_34454.66.json,2018/10/27  12.38.54,,Not_Found


    I tried below script unable get thru.
    Request your kind help. 


Processed_File=/test/Processed_Files.csv
ReportFile=Report.csv
LoopCounter=0
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2
do
if [ $LoopCounter != 0 ]
then 
printf '%s' $f1 >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' , >> $ReportFile
printf '%s' $f2 >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' , >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' , >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s\n' , >> $ReportFile
                #printf '\n'  >> $ReportFile
else
                printf '%s' Input File >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' , >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' Start Date >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' , >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' Response File Name>> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' , >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' End Date >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s' , >> $ReportFile
                printf '%s\n' Status>> $ReportFile
fi 
let LoopCounter=LoopCounter+1
done <$Processed_File
```

Comment: I don't see your script.

Comment: Can you edit the question and put it there, so that it is more readable?

Comment: I have added the script in question. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR&&NR>1{split($1,b,"."); split(b[2],status,"_"); map[b[1]"."status[1]]=$0","status[2]} NR!=FNR&&FNR>1{split($1,a,"."); search_string=a[1]"."a[2]; if(search_string in map) {map[search_string]=$0","map[search_string]} else {map[search_string]=$0",,Not_Found"}} END{print "Input File Name,Start Date,Output File Name,End Time/Date,Status"; for (i in map) print map[i]}' Responsed_File_Name.csv Processed_files.csv > Report.csv
```

Comment: Input File Name,Start Date,Output File Name,End Time/Date,Status

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: When i am changing the data it is not giving proper output

Processed_files.csv

Input File Name,Start Date
OutwardHSNSummary_2292_3532_09_2018_31102018033553.035.json,2018/10/31  15.35.58

Comment: Responsed_File_Name.csv

Output File Name,End Time/Date
OutwardHSNSummary_2292_3532_09_2018_31102018033553.035_SUCCESS.csv,2018/10/31  15.42.31

Comment: Report (not coming in proper format)

Input File Name,Start Date,Output File Name,End Time/Date,Status
OutwardHSNSummary_2292_3532_09_2018_31102018033553.035_SUCCESS.csv,2018/10/31  15.42.31,2018
OutwardHSNSummary_2292_3532_09_2018_31102018033553.035.json,2018/10/31  15.35.58,,Not_Found

Comment: Edited the answer. Try now. Problem was due to the changed indexes in the input. Have tried to handle it more generically now.

Comment: Hi, i Need your help in above awk code, I have added two more column in input file STN,Sec,Input File Name,Start Date and now i want the first two column to come as it is in report and rest same as earlier.

Comment: **STN,Sec,Input File Name,Start Date**
    234xxxxxx2343,TBTG,Out_ch_pc_88882.77.json,2018/10/26  16.38.54


  **Output File Name,End Time/Date**

    Out_ch_pc_88882.77_SUCCESS.csv,2018/10/30  14.53.26


**STN,Sec,Input File Name,Start Date,Output File Name,End Time/Date,Status**

    234xxxxxx2343,TBTG,Out_ch_pc_88882.77.json,2018/10/26  16.38.54,Out_ch_pc_88882.77_SUCCESS.csv,2018/10/30  14.53.26,SUCCESS

Comment: Thanks it worked with below code. awk -F',' 'NR==FNR&&NR>1{split($1,b,"."); split(b[2],status,"_"); map[b[1]"."status[1]]=$0","status[2]} NR!=FNR&&FNR>1{split($1,a,"."); search_string=c[1]"."c[2]; if(search_string in map) {map[search_string]=$0","map[search_string]} else {map[search_string]=$0",,Not_Found"}} END{print "STN,Sec,Input File Name,Start Date,Output File Name,End Time/Date,Status"; for (i in map) print map[i]}' Responsed_File_Name.csv Processed_files.csv > Report.csv